# sqlite3.OperationalError: near : syntax error But Running Fine on Different Program

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
cursor = conn.execute(
            "select * from "+match + " where player='"+nm+"'")
```

This same Code is Running fine in Different Program.
Am getting This Error

```
File "d:evaluatewindow.py", line 204, in calculate
    cursor = conn.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "where": syntax error
```

What could be the Possible Reason for This?

**Match Contains Following Data[image: match table]**

Comment: Whatever's in `match` is presumably to blame

Comment: Please show us what `match` contains.

Comment: Thanks!. I have added The match table.

Comment: Not the match table, the `match` python variable. This error will come if python variable `match` is empty string.

Comment: Yes you are Correct, It was Because there was Nothing in Match Variable.